# Copy a 2D array to make it 3D

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose that I have a 2D Numpy array, `A`.

I want to build a 3D array `B` with depth of 100 such that for every `i` such that `0 <= i < 100`, we have `B[:,:,i] == A`.

Is there any efficient way to do this in Python/Numpy?

Comment: `B = np.tile(A[..., None], (1, 1, 100))`.  But in general you'd tend to avoid needless repetition and make use of NumPy's [broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make a zero 3D array of your desired shape, and add your `A` to it

```
In [13]:

A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
In [14]:

C = np.zeros(shape=(A.shape[0], A.shape[1], 100), dtype=A.dtype))
In [15]:

B = C+A[...,...,np.newaxis]
In [16]:

B[:,:,1]
Out[16]:
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6]])
In [17]:

B[:,:,2]
Out[17]:
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6]])
```

It is not going to be 100 copies of `A`, (and I doubt if you can ever make it so), because `B` has to be a contiguous memory block by itself.

Comment: You probably want to fix the dtype of `C` to be the same as that of `A`.  In the example above, `A` and `B` have different dtypes.

Comment: @MarkDickinson, that's a very good point. `np.zero` defaults to crank out `float`.